# Jackson custom date formatter

Tags: json, spring-boot, datetime, jackson

I want to serialize a Json object with a date field, into a Pojo.
For example

```
{
   date: <some arbitrary date format>
}
```

to

```
@JsonFormat(???)
LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

The problem is that the date can be in any number of formats.  For example, maybe just a year, just a date, or date and time.  And even those can be in multiple formats.

```
2021
2021-5-23
2021/05/23
2021/05/23 02:07
2021-05-23 02:07:53
2021/05/23 02:07:50.567
```

I've already written a parser that has a list of formats and will loop through them until it finds one that works.  How can I write a custom Jackson serializer or formatter that uses that code and can take a string from a Json object and properly convert it to a Date or LocalDateTime object in the Pojo?

If it makes a difference, I'm also doing this in SpringBoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are talking about DEserializing? If so, you can create your own [`JsonDeserializer`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonDeserializer.html) that supports `LocalDateTime` and register it with [`JsonComponent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/jackson/JsonComponent.html). This would look like this:

(The "input" can be accessed via `p.getText()`)

```
@JsonComponent
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

  @Override
  public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    String stringValue = p.getText();
    // Use your parser instead of this
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("yyyy[-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0).toFormatter();
    return LocalDateTime.parse(stringValue, formatter);
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I meant deserializing.  Thank you.  I'll try out what you suggested